# Hypothesis testing hight z value

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, standard-deviation, assumptions

I am taking baby steps in statistics and after going through Hypothesis testing tutorials I took simple data set for try out. 
[Date set here](https://github.com/zygmuntz/wine-quality/blob/master/winequality/winequality-red.csv)

I will take you through my thinking and steps I took.

1. I defined my question - Whether alcohol quantity improves quality of
   wine.
2. Null hypotheses - it doesn't alternative - it does.
3. I Cleared data set and split in two samples. One (10 entries), 
   where only vines with quality level 3 and alcohol level and second
   sample (18 entires) quality level 8 and representing alcohol level.
4. Calculated mean and standard deviations. For quality 8 - alcohol mean = 12.09; std = 1,22. For quality 8 - alcohol mean = 9,955; std = 0,818
5. Made assumption, that difference between alcohol in quality group 3 and group 8 is larger than standard deviation, then it would mean that amount of alcohol must impact wine quality. Still wanted to test with Z scores etc
6. To do next steps H0 hypotheses stated that alcohol amount in wine doesn't impact quality of wine. Therefore mean alcohol amount of vine in quality level 3 must be similar with alcohol amount in vine quality level 8.
7. Now I need to calculate standard deviation of sampling distribution - taking std of level 3 alcohol - 0.818 / Sqrt(10) = 0.258
8. Now calculating Z score (to know how far am I from mean) - mean alcohol amount of level 8 quality subtracted by level 3 alcohol quality mean and divided by standard deviation of sampling distribution. 12.09 - 9.955 / 0.258 = 8.275

And the situation is that this result doesn't correspond to Z score table, that means that somewhere in my logic I got wrong. Where My assumptions/calculations etc are wrong? any advices?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't correspond" here?

Comment: Z score table is from -3 to 0 and +3. In interval (-3 -> 3). My z score is 8,275 and that doesn't fir in this range

Comment: That doesn't imply the calculations were wrong (they might be but this doesn't tell us they were) -- only that your table doesn't go past 3. If you got 2.97 instead of 8.275 what would your p-value have been? (what about 2.99? What about 3?)